# how to handle error of websocket in flutter

Tags: node.js, flutter, websocket

I try making real time chat using node.js, express, and socket io in backend... and then I am using flutter for client-side... the problem is... I get error that say:

```
D/FlutterSocketIoPlugin: SocketIO(22042): connect_error: [{"cause":{"detailMessage":"Expected HTTP 101 response but was \u0027404 Not Found\u0027","stackTrace":[],"suppressedExceptions":[]},"detailMessage":"websocket error","stackTrace":[],"suppressedExceptions":[]}]
D/FlutterSocketIoPlugin: SocketIO(22042): reconnect_error: [{"cause":{"cause":{"detailMessage":"Expected HTTP 101 response but was \u0027404 Not Found\u0027","stackTrace":[],"suppressedExceptions":[]},"detailMessage":"websocket error","stackTrace":[],"suppressedExceptions":[]},"detailMessage":"Connection error","stackTrace":[],"suppressedExceptions":[]}]
```

is there something that I miss here?

Comment: use future to handle that error.future has on error part that helps you handle that